# How to use string 'show' to trigger jquery show function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like this:

```
var showTest = (condition) => {
    if (condition === 'show') {
        $('#id1').show();
        $('#id2').show();
        $('#id3').show();
    }
    else if (condition === 'hide') {
        $('#id1').hide();
        $('#id2').hide();
        $('#id3').hide();
    }
};
```

It works great. But if the argument 'condition' is always 'show' and 'hide', I feel that the if else is not needed as the function is just show() and hide()? So does jQuery allow me to do this and get rid of if else?

```
var showTest = (condition) => {
    $('#id1').condition();
    $('#id2').condition();
    $('#id3').condition();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - use bracket notation like so:

```
var showTest = condition => {
    $("#id1")[condition]();
    $("#id2")[condition]();
    $("#id3")[condition]();
};
```

And make it more concise using one call to `$`:

```
var showTest = condition => {
    $("#id1, #id2, #id3")[condition]();
};
```

Comment: If there are different conditions, can I do it like this: 
```$("#id1, #id2, #id3")[condition1, condition2, condition3]();```, where condition1 is for id1, condition2 is for id2, condition3 is for id3?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu I think that's not possible. `#id1` is your selector, and `condition1` is a like an input parameter which varies based on input.  You cannot just simply map those two items directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map your condition to your element, you can try the code below as an example.

```
    var conditionArray = [condition1, condition2, condition3];
    var [conditionA, conditionB, conditionC] = conditionArray;

    var showTest1 = $("#id1")[conditionA]();
    var showTest2 = $("#id2")[conditionB]();
    var showTest3 = $("#id3")[conditionC]();
```

This approach is using array destructuring which unpacked the items from the array and assign to a distinct variables.